# Cant find state variable

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {
    state = { albums: [] } ;

    componentWillMount(){
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then(response => this.setState({ albums : response.data }));
    }


    renderAlbums(){
        return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{albums.title}</Text>)
    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <View>
               {this.renderAlbums()}
            </View>
    );
    }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

It says "referenceError: Can't find variable: albums " it popped up out of nowhere after working, do you know what is happening?

Comment: Change `renderAlbums(){` to `renderAlbums = () => {`

Comment: Thank you Dan! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a mismatch with your mapping variable. In:

```
return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{albums.title}</Text>)
```

You're using `album` as the variable name for the function, but then referencing `albums.title`.

Comment: oh yeah, did it!